# Having trouble to boot from USB on my notebook

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb

My Asus notebook is super slow and is running windows 10 64bit. I need help replaying the OS to something lighter.

So I download the 32bit disk image file of Ubuntu 16.04.01 from the website's download section, and then use `rufus` to add it onto my 8gb USB stick.

Once that's finished I plug it into my notebook and restart into the BIOS and then set the boot option to the USB stick as number `1`. I hit `save and exit` and then it just goes ahead to booting into windows.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try the 64 bit image maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have disabled secure boot. In the boot options there will probably be an option to boot from CSM or Legacy, select this option. Also check to see if there is a Quickboot option, and if so, disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also download the ubuntu to a CD or USB stick. Then go to BIOS and go loacte the SHIMX file and enable to boot from it. AFTER you need to install ubuntu via instructions and afterward, when you reboot, you should see grub.